# Calling wordpress API from Zend pages on same box

Tags: api, wordpress

What is the best way to load the WordPress API from a Zend Powered page, so I can call it on `.php` pages outside of the WordPress installation?

I currently have this code on a `.php` page outside of WordPress:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

I try and run the page and get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::set_prefix() in
>   /wordpress/wp-settings.php on line 268

I have been trying to troubleshoot the problem using some of the suggestions on this page.  But to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting exactly the same issue as you are above. I don't think the problem is specifically that you are trying to load from outside WordPress. It is because the above code is being called from *inside a function*, outside of WordPress.

I am not using the Zend framework, but when I try to access WordPress using the code above, it's no problem. When I try to load it from the context of my CMS (within a function) I get the same error as above.

Sorry I can't help, but I thought my observation might help someone find a solution.

Comment: I tried taking the call out of a function.  Still same error.  Thanks for the advice though!!!!